# AWS lambda spring . Not able to load properties file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have  problem with loading the properties file where i reference the values from. Locally I am able to run it as expected. But AWS lambda function does not seem to work as expected since it is not able to laod properties file. Below is the handler written. I deploy MainHanlder.java function on lambda.

```
 @Component
    public class TestHandler implements RequestHandler<SNSEvent, Object> {



        @Override
        public String handleRequest(SNSEvent snsEvent, Context context) {


            TestClient testClient = Application.getBean("pp",TestClient);
        return null;
    }
    }
```

MainHandler.java

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
    import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SNSEvent;
    import com.test.lambda.ApplicationConfiguration;


    public class MainHandler extends SpringRequestHandler<SNSEvent, Object> {

        /**
         * Here we create the Spring {@link ApplicationContext} that will
         * be used throughout our application.
         */
        private static final ApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

        @Override
        public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
            return context;
        }

    }
```

SpringRequestHandler.java

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public abstract class SpringRequestHandler<I, O> implements RequestHandler<I, O>, ApplicationContextProvider {

    private final RequestHandler<I, O> handler;

    public SpringRequestHandler() {
        handler = getApplicationContext().getBean(RequestHandler.class);
    }

    @Override
    public O handleRequest(final I input, final Context context) {
        return (O) handler.handleRequest(input, context);
    }
}
```

Application.java

```
public class Application {

    private static final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext springContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    private static boolean flag = Boolean.TRUE;
    private static final XLogger logger = XLoggerFactory.getXLogger(Application.class);



    public static <T> T getBean(String env, Class<T> clazz) {


        InputStream i1 = null;
        InputStream i2 = null;

        if(flag) {
            Properties rp = new Properties();
            Properties ap = new Properties();

            try {

                System.out.println("print env " + env);

                i1 = Application.class.getResourceAsStream(“/application-” + env + ".properties");
        rp.load(i1);

        i2 = Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/application-" + env + ".properties");
        ap.load(i2);

        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyOverrideConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
                propertyOverrideConfigurer.setPropertiesArray(new Properties[]{rp,ap});

                springContext.scan(new String[]{"com.pinto.lambda"});
                springContext.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(propertyOverrideConfigurer);


try {
                    springContext.refresh();
                }catch(IllegalStateException e) {
                }

                flag = Boolean.FALSE;


            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Exception in the Application - " +e.getMessage());
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load properties " + e.getMessage());
            }


return springContext.getBean(clazz);

}
```

ERROR TRACE -  AWS CONSOLE LOGS

```
==================== FUNCTION OUTPUT ====================
{"errorMessage":"Unable to load properties null","errorType":"java.lang.RuntimeException","stackTrace":["com.pinto.lambda.Application.getBean(Application.java:65)","com.pinto.lambda.handler.GetWarehouseInventoryHandler.handleRequest(TestHandler.java:44)","com.pinto.lambda.handler.GetWarehouseInventoryHandler.handleRequest(TestHandler.java:1)","com.pinto.lambda.handler.SpringRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringRequestHandler.java:19)"]}
==================== FUNCTION LOG OUTPUT ====================

print env pp
[ERROR] Exception in the Application - null
Unable to load properties null: java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load properties null
    at com.pinto.lambda.Application.getBean(Application.java:65)
    at com.pinto.lambda.handler.TestHandler.handleRequest(TestHandler.java:44)
    at com.pinto.lambda.handler.TestHandler.handleRequest(TestHandler.java:1)
    at com.pinto.lambda.handler.SpringRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringRequestHandler.java:19)
```

Comment: Stop catching exceptions and ignoring them, or their stack trace. You're hiding the cause of the problem, and thus shoot yourself in the foot. Also, please, indent your code. It's not that hard.

Comment: @JBNizet, If you can be more specific, it will be good. I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: Remove `catch(IllegalStateException e) {}`. Remove `catch (Exception e) { ... }`. And then you'll have the type, message and stack trace of the actual exception that is being thrown.

Comment: @JBNizet catch(IllegalStateException e) {} is for inner try. There is another catch (Exception e) { ... } for outer try which is being caught and that can be seen in Logs. What happens is , it fails in outer try block even before going to inner try block

Comment: So? You're ignoring an exception that indicates a bug (the IllegalStateException). And you're hiding the actual type, and cause of the exception you're catching in the outer catch block. But if you really don't want to know what the problem is, keep everything as is.